# Show a map is a bijection?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, linear-programming

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be sets and let $f: A \longrightarrow C$ and $g: B \longrightarrow D$ be *bijections*.

How can I show show that the map $m: A \times B \longrightarrow C \times D$ given by $m(a,b) = ( f(a), g(b) )$ is a *bijection*?

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your thoughts? What do you think need to be proven, what is the meaning of the map being a bijection? You have tried to solve it yourself haven't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injectivity: Suppose 
$$
m(a,b)=m(x,y)\implies (f(a),g(b))=(f(x),g(y))\implies f(a)=f(x),\;\text{and}\; g(b)=g(y)
$$
which then forces $b=y$ and $x=a$ by injectivity of $f$ and $g$.

Surjectivity: Let $(z,w)\in C\times D$. Then $z\in C$ and by surjectivity of $f$, there is some $a\in A$ with $f(a)=z$. The argument for $g$ is identical. Thus we have found $(a,b)$ with $m(a,b)=(z,w)$.